# Blogger - displayed text on hover image is offset and differ from calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset, blogger

I was recently writing a 'show text on hover image' code for my blog. After I finished writing it in codepen and started testing it in my blog, I found the code written in codepen does not work in Blogger. I reviewed the code for around 3 hours, I still cannot find out what is wrong with my code.
[image]
Live page (where the code does not work): http://ll5555.blogspot.com/p/test.html
Code in codepen (where the code works fine):

```js
$(".hptable img").attr('class', 'gthumb');
$(".hptable td").hover(function() {
  $.title = $(this).children().attr('title');
  if (typeof $.title !== typeof undefined && $.title !== false) {
    $.title = $.title.replace(/\n/, "<br />");
    $(this).children().after("<div class=title>" + $.title + "</div>");
    $(this).children().removeAttr('title');
  }
  $(this).children().next("div.title").show();
}, function() {
  $(this).children().next("div.title").hide();
});
$(".hptable tr td").mousemove(function(e) {
  var width = $(this).children().next('div.title').width();
  var height = $(this).children().next('div.title').height();
  $(this).children().next("div.title").css("top", e.pageY - height);
  $(this).children().next("div.title").css("left", e.pageX  - width / 2);
});
```

```css
.hptable {
    text-align:center;
}
.hptable td:hover:not(.v):not(.h) {
    background-color: #CEE9FF;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
.cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 176px;
    max-width: 177px;
    height: 176px;
    max-height: 177px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #87CEEB !important;
    background-color: #D9F9FF;
}
.hptable img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width: 175px;
    max-height: 175px;
}
.hptable .h {
    height: 30px;
}
.hptable .v {
    width: 30px;
}
.title {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width:auto;
height:auto;
display:none;
color: white;
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow:
1px 1px 0 #000,
0 0 2px #5F84CE, 0 0 3px #4C6AA5;
white-space: nowrap !important;
}
.hptable tr td, .hptable tr, .label:before, .label:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
       -o-transition: all 1.5s;
          transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding: 50px;">
<hr/><h1>GAME SHARE</h1><hr/>
<table class="hptable">
<tr>
<td class="null h"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="null cell">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AcqrCtG.png" title="機動戦士ガンダム ガンダムVS.ガンダムNEXT PLUS
Gundam vs. Gundam NEXT PLUS" />
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not offset your `top` position to compensate on Blogger?

Comment: Bloggers do have lots of div tags, it is hard to find out the element that `title` is using to reference/position its `absolute` position relative to that element. This siituation looks like I have to give up the code that I spent a half day in it. :|

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's following the cursor nicely. Just offset tour `top` position.

Comment: Do you mean correct the offset by adjusting the `title` positioning algorithm? I know I can do that but I do not know how the code will respond to a wider screen 'cause I am using a 4:3 screen.

Comment: http://cybercrab.com/screencheck/

Comment: @Daerik, the site does not work with some scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved finally, what a mess in jQuery...
You can see the difference when you use the code in Blogger.
The code basically throws the current `<div class="titles">...</div>` to the end of `<body>...</body>` when hovering an image.
And when no longer hovering an image, the code throws the div tag back to the original place.
A small reminder: you cannot move the mouse too fast, if not, the div tag will disappear.

```js
$(".hptable img").attr('class', 'gthumb');
$(".hptable tr td:not(.v):not(.h)").hover(function() {
  $.title = $(this).children().attr('title');
  if (typeof $.title !== typeof undefined && $.title !== false) {
    $.title = $.title.replace(/\n/, "<br />");
    $(this).children().after("<div class=titles>" + $.title + "</div>");
    $(this).children().removeAttr('title');
  }
  $(this).children().next("div.titles").appendTo($("body"));
  $(".titles:last").show();
}, function() {
  $(".titles:last").hide();
  $(".titles:last").appendTo($(this));
});
$(".hptable tr td:not(.v):not(.h)").mousemove(function(e) {
  var width = $(".titles:last").width();
  var height = $(".titles:last").height();
  var widths = $(this).parent().parent().parent().position().left;
  var heights = $(this).parent().parent().parent().position().top;
  $(".titles:last").css("top", e.pageY - height - 10 );
  $(".titles:last").css("left", e.pageX  - width / 2 );
});
```

```css
.hptable {
    text-align:center;
}
.hptable td:hover:not(.v):not(.h) {
    background-color: #CEE9FF;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
.cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 176px;
    max-width: 177px;
    height: 176px;
    max-height: 177px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #87CEEB !important;
    background-color: #D9F9FF;
}
.hptable img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width: 175px;
    max-height: 175px;
}
.hptable .h {
    height: 30px;
}
.hptable .v {
    width: 30px;
}
.titles {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width:auto;
height:auto;
display:none;
color: white;
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow:
1px 1px 0 #000,
0 0 2px #5F84CE, 0 0 3px #4C6AA5;
white-space: nowrap !important;
}
.hptable tr td, .hptable tr, .label:before, .label:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
       -o-transition: all 1.5s;
          transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding: 50px;">
<hr/><h1>GAME SHARE</h1><hr/>
<table class="hptable">
<tr>
<td class="null h"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="null cell">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AcqrCtG.png" title="機動戦士ガンダム ガンダムVS.ガンダムNEXT PLUS
Gundam vs. Gundam NEXT PLUS" />
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.title` element (which follows the cursor) is being positioned on the page with the `position: absolute` attribute, which offsets pixels "at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)).

On your blogger page, one of the parent elements (`.post-body`) has `position: relative;` set, which is why the coordinates are "off" compared to your CodePen. You'll just need to do math to adjust the position accordingly for that element, or on a closer child that you put `position: relative` on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found a solution.